# Redux-forms Call alternate submit from ComponentWillRecieveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

**redux-forms version:** 6.6.3

**react version:** 15.5.0

I want to call different submit functions from componentWillRecieveProps function in my react component.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

 if (nextProps.updateTierConfigState == "ValidationFulfilled" 
            && nextProps.updateMyConfigValidationClean) {
  console.log('CWRP calling submit()')
  //this.props.submit(); //THIS CALLS DEFAULT on FORM's onSubmit
  this.props.handleSubmit(this.updateSubmit().bind(this))

 }    
 else {
  this.props.handleSubmit(this.createSubmit().bind(this))
 }
}

updateSubmit(values) { 
  //do stuff
}

createSubmit(values) { 
  //do stuff
}
```

I have see examples like this: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/711#issuecomment-191850962

But, I have not been able to call handleSubmit successfully. It does not call the passed in function.

I have debugged into handleSubmit and it returns very quickly with out calling the specified submit function.

Comment: Need to see the `this.props.handleSubmit` function to debug this.

Comment: Not directly related, but I think your nesting in your if statement is off. There's two ending braces after the if block and an else block floating outside of `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: @Jose, the missing } only exists in the post above, not in my actual code. Will correct, still.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda,
The handleSubmit is implemented by the redux-form library.

Comment: Check out http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/submitValidation/.

"Pass it as an onSubmit prop to your decorated component. In which case, you would use onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} inside your decorated component to cause it to fire when the submit button is clicked.
Pass it as a parameter to the this.props.handleSubmit function from inside your decorated component. In which case, you would use onClick={this.props.handleSubmit(mySubmit)} inside your decorated component to cause it to fire when the submit button is clicked."

Answer (score 2):

You are immediately invoking the functions when you pass them in. When you reference the submit functions, you don't need to include the `()` after the function name. `this.updateSubmit().bind(this)` should be `this.updateSubmit`. You also don't need the bind here.

Change: `this.props.handleSubmit(this.updateSubmit().bind(this))`

To: `this.props.handleSubmit(this.updateSubmit)`

Comment: Thanks, I made the mistake of putting () after updateSubmit. However, after fixing that, the handleSubmit still does not call the function updateSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I needed to do two things.

1. Invoke the custom submit method using this line: `this.props.handleSubmit((values)=> this.submitUpdate(values))()` Note the added "()" at the end.
2. Move this line (and a surrounding if condition) to the componentDidUpdate() method. I'm using props in the submit method to decide the state of validation of the component and the props from mapStateToProps are not assigned to this.props before `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillUpdate`.

Here is my new automatic submit call:

```
componentDidUpdate() {

 //moved this here so that this.props is updated from nextState
 if (this.props.updateMyConfigState == "ValidationFulfilled" 
            && this.props.updateMyConfigValidationClean) {

        this.props.handleSubmit((values) => this.submitUpdate(values))();            

 }
}
```

I am aware that this is outside of the redux-form recommendation for validation and I recognize that this this might not be the best way to handle validation. My current reasoning is:

1. It allows me to have multiple submission validation actions (separates ones for create and update user actions) where each has their own error and warnings behavior. In particular, Error: disallow action and WarningsOnly: allow but require extra user approval.
2. Visually present the errors/warnings in a separate list outside of the gui elements.